# Ignoring files under config folder of codeigniter using github not working

Tags: github, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter framework to develope simple application. I want to push my code to github repo. While publishing my code to repo i want to ignore set of files in config folder such as config.php, database.php etc. I have downloaded codeigniter 3.1.11 from official website. I have been using following conditions inside my **.gitignore** file but none of them are working for me. I have tried all possible combinations of below conditions.

1. /application/config/
2. /application/config/*
3. /application/config/*.php
4. /application/config/database.php
5. /application/config/config.php
6. application/config/
7. application/config/*
8. application/config/*.php
9. application/config/database.php
10. application/config/config.php
11. config/config.php
12. config/*
13. /config/*.php
14. */config

Whenever i change my config file for localhost setup and check the status it displays config file has been modified, and changes ready to be staged.
Help me to get throught this problem. I have tried all the possible options over the internet as well but none of them are working.

Answer (score 1):

First, whenever a `.gitignore` set of rule does not work for a given file, check why with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- /path/to/file/which/should/be/ignored
```

Second, it is easier to put a `.gitignore` in the config folder itself, and list the files you don't want.

Third, for any file you want to be ignored, double-check they are not already tracked:

```
git rm --cached file_to_ignore
```